# Access private static property in static class in test

Tags: php, phpunit

Is it possible to access the `$measurements` property in a test case?

```
class Performance
{
    private static $measurements = [];

    public static function createMeasurement()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So far I tries something like this:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class(Performance));
$property = $reflection->getProperty('measurements');
$property->setAccessible(true);
```

But this does not work, because `Use of undefined constant Performance - assumed 'Performance'`. How do I tell php to get an object from a static class?

Comment: you cannot access it directly from outside the class because it is private meaning it can only be accessed from within it's own class. However you can create a function called GetMeasurements() and return the private variable there. Then simply call that function from any other class.

Comment: There is also Reflection in PHP that will allow you to duplicate the class and check the private variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) takes an object as argument, so make one and pass it along

```
$p = new Performance;

$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($p)); // or
// $reflection = new \ReflectionClass('Performance'); // without get_class

$property = $reflection->getProperty('measurements');
$property->setAccessible(true);
var_dump($property);
var_dump($property->getValue($p));
```

Will output

```
object(ReflectionProperty)#3 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "measurements"
  ["class"]=>
  string(11) "Performance"
}

// my property is an array [1,2,3]
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Also in your class you need to properly define the `createMeasurement` function

```
private static function createMeasurement(){
                 ^^
```

Answer (score 8):

You also can access private properties with [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). You just need to [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) them to the class scope.

```
$getMeasurements = function() { return static::$measurements; };
$getPerformanceMeasurements = $getMeasurements->bindTo(null, Performance::class);

$measurements = $getPerformanceMeasurements();
```

Comment: This is a really neat way to solve this issue - thanks for sharing it!

Comment: You can even wrap it all in parentheses and use an arrow function, to directly get the value $measurements = ((fn() => static::$measurements)->bindTo(null, Performance::class))();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$reflectionProperty = new ReflectionProperty('Performance', 'measurements');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
echo $reflectionProperty->getValue();
```